# The most efficient way to calculate total number of all descendants in self reference table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am looking for an efficient way to calculate total number of all sub categories (all levels) for a given category, without retrieving all the data from the database

Here is my Model:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        SubCategories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentCategory")]
    public Guid? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
    public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public CategoryViewModel()
    {
        SubCategories = new List<CategoryViewModel>();
    }

    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual CategoryViewModel ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual List<CategoryViewModel> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public int TotalOfDirectSubCategories { get; set; }
    public int TotalOfAllSubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

My AutoMapping:

```
            cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>()
            .PreserveReferences()                
            .ReverseMap();
```

And finally my EF to retrieve data:

```
                data = _ctx.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == categoryId)
                //.Include(x => x.SubCategories)
                .ToList();
```

Let's assume a category can contain thousands of sub categories. Since this will be SOA solution, and data will be passed from Web API into my client app, I don't want to pass all subCategories data with every web API call, so I will only need data for requested category, and corresponding counts.

Let assume we have
'cat 1' > 'cat 1 1' > 'cat 1 1 1'

'cat 1' contains exactly 2 sub categories. 'cat 1 1' contains one sub category. I can retrieve 'cat 1' data by calling web API method 'getCategory(null)', and to retrieve 'cat 1 1' data I would call 'getCategory(GuidOfCat11)'

For 'cat 1':

TotalOfDirectSubCategories - 1

TotalOfAllSubCategories - 2

And again, no subCategories will be included

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best I could implement, do you think there is a better approach:

AutoMapper:

```
            cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>()
            .PreserveReferences()
            .ForMember(x => x.TotalOfDirectSubCategories, x => x.MapFrom(z => z.SubCategories.Count))
            .ReverseMap();
```

Populating CategoryViewModel:

```
        public List<CategoryViewModel> GetAllCategoriesAndTasksForParentCategoryAndUser(Guid? categoryId)
    {
        var data = new List<Category>();

        if (categoryId == null) // retrieve root level categories
        {
                data = _ctx.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == null)
                    .Include(x => x.SubCategories)
                    .Include(x => x.Tasks)
                    .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
                data = _ctx.Categories.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId)
                    .Include(x => x.SubCategories)
                    .Include(x => x.Tasks)
                    .ToList();
        }

        var dataToReturn = Mapper.Map<List<Category>, List<CategoryViewModel>>(data);
        foreach (var category in data)
        {
            var vm = dataToReturn.First(x => x.CategoryId == category.CategoryId);

            //subCategories
            int totalCount = 0;
            SubCategoriesCount(ref totalCount, category);
            vm.TotalOfAllSubCategories = totalCount;            
        }

        return dataToReturn;

    }
```

And finally, the method:

```
    private void SubCategoriesCount(ref int subCatCount, Category category)
    {
        if (category.SubCategories != null || category.SubCategories.Count() != 0)
        {
            subCatCount += category.SubCategories.Count();

            foreach (var subCat in category.SubCategories)
            {
                SubCategoriesCount(ref subCatCount, subCat);
            }
        }
    }
```